# Is there a higher-order version of cumtrapz()?

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

## Introduction

Suppose I have `N` points `x(1:N)` at which I have function values `f(1:N)`, for example:

```
x = [ 0.0795, 0.1327, 0.1395, 0.5133, 0.6470, 0.7358, 0.7640 ];
f = [ 0.0388, 0.4774, 0.4547, 0.0784, 0.3241, 0.2818, 0.9667 ];
```

I want to calculate the cumulative integral of `f` with respect to `x` using these data.

## Low-Order Solution

In MATLAB, I can do this easily using [`cumtrapz()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumtrapz.html):

```
>> result = cumtrapz( x, f )

result =

     0    0.0137    0.0169    0.1165    0.1434    0.1703    0.1879
```

## Problem

Unfortunately, `cumtrapz()` uses the trapezoidal method for numerical integration, which is insufficient for my purposes.

[Higher-order methods exist](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/lab/people/sd/lectures/nummeth98/integration.htm), like Simpson's Rule, but to my knowledge there isn't a function that performs the cumulative version of Simpson's Rule for nonuniform grids at the MATLAB File Exchange, or anywhere else.

**Does a higher-order version of cumtrapz() already exist? If not, what would I have to do to implement it myself?**

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but if you have the function (not just its values) you can use [`integral`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html), which uses an adaptive quadrature method

Comment: Yeah, I need to approximate the integral without the function — just the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of another method however you could use an interpolation with a `pchip`, `spline`, or some other method to increase the resolution.  Then use `cumtrapz` to get a closer approximation of the numeric integral.

It would be up to you to determine what method is applicable to your function.

Example using a sine function and spline

```
>> x = linspace(0,pi,5);
>> f = sin(x);
>> intF = cumtrapz(x,f);
error = 2-intF(end)
error =
    0.1039

>> x2 = linspace(x(1),x(end),numel(x)*10); %Up sample by 10x
>> f2 = interp1(x,f,x2,'spline');   %Interpolate with spline
>> intF2 = cumtrapz(x2,f2);
>> error = 2-intF2(end)  %MUCH LESS ERROR
error =
   -0.0038
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like this could be expected to work best for functions that act like 2nd-order piecewise polynomials, right? In other words, is it correct to assume that it’d be less accurate for functions that have significant higher-order derivatives?

Comment: spline and pchip are both cubic piece-wise but yes I suppose if you had a higher order function and a slow enough sample rate such that there is lots of deviation between sample you could expect less accurate results ... my comment to that would be ... if that is the case increase the sample rate so you aren't missing wild swings in your data. 
  https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2012/07/16/splines-and-pchips/